# Kafka logs folder too huge

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We have lots of data (from 14 months) in our kafka logs folder. Kafka is writing these by default.

```
Location of server.xml: /install/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2/config/server.xml

 Here is the setting in server.xml:   log.dirs=/install/kafka-logs
```

1. I want to delete last years logs. Will this cause any problems? Do i need to 
   stop kafka or can i disable last years logs while it is running?
2. how do i disable/reduce logging to this folder?

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if the terminology confuses you – the contents of this folder are not log files in the sense that logs such as "Kafka Broker started" are logged there. It contains the log files that incoming messages are appended to, so this folder contains your valuable Kafka data.

You should set a proper retention time on your topics (and a sensible default on broker level) so that messages are cleared up when they are no longer needed (default is 7 days). Messages will be kept at least for that time period and may be deleted at any time after that (it's not a strict timestamp due to the structure of the log files).

For 1: you can change retention time on topic level at runtime
`bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <zk> --alter --topic <topic> --config retention.ms=<retention in ms>`

2: The only way to reduce this is to a) send fewer messages or b) reduce the replication factor of your topics. This is probably not what your after.

Comment: thanks for your response. Our retention time is set to 7 days.                              But /kafka-logs has data from the last 14 months.                                                       Not sure what is happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry i meant this:  /install/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2/logs.                                            NOT /install/kafka-logs

Comment: @josh you can delete logs/* directory contents. Kafka-logs/* directory has your actual data which can be deleted using retention period.